# Маршрут для ipv6 подсети через netplan

Tags: ubuntu, route, ipv6

Настроил netplan по man'ам, работает, так же получаю ipv6 адрес автоматически по NDP. Хочу добавить маршрут на подсеть ipv6 вручную на хосте через netplan, как это сделать правильно?

Вот текущий конфиг:

```
network:
version: 2
ethernets:
  enp3s0:
    dhcp4: no
bridges:
  br0:
    interfaces: [enp3s0]
    macaddress: 40:16:7e:73:АА:FF
    dhcp4: true

    routes:
      - to: 2001:xxx:xxxx:xxx:xxx:xxx::/124
        via: 2001:xxx:xxxx:xxx::
```

Без секции route все работает.

Comment: Может `- to` поменять на `to`?

Comment: К сожалению, это не помогло. Да и в документации явно указано, что секция должна начинаться с `- to`